# Custom hover-effect for WPF button with strange behaviour

Tags: wpf, hover, mouseover

I have a simple button containing an image:

```
    <Button x:Name="helpBtn" Width="25" Style="{StaticResource HoverButton}" Template="{StaticResource hoverButtonTemplate}" Click="onHelpButtonClicked" ToolTip="{x:Static resx:language.HelpButton}" Height="25" BorderThickness="0" Canvas.Top="2" Canvas.Right="52" Canvas.Left="-77">
       <Image x:Name="helpImg" Source="Resources/2_help.png" Width="6" Height="10" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Button>
```

Then I have this ContentTemplate:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="hoverButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="hoverRect2" Fill="DarkGreen" Visibility="Hidden" Opacity="0.2" Width="{TemplateBinding Button.Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Button.Height}"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle x:Name="hoverRect" Fill="Black" Visibility="Hidden" Opacity="1" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Width}" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Height}" Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Margin}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Stretch}" ImageSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Source}"/>
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="hoverRect" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="hoverRect2" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

The problem is, that the mouse pointer always needs to move over the image (which is showing a small questionmark with transparent background). So the mouse pointer needs to hover exactly the question mark before the hover-effect for the button becomes visible. If the hover-effect became active and the mouse leaves the question-mark but is still inside the button-area, everything is fine. What's the reason for this strange behaviour?

Comment: As gomi says, this is because WPF mouse detection ignores empty areas, like the area around your image. It then detects that area because it is no longer empty, but filled with your rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF does not use the rectangle's dimensions to detect whether the mouse is inside (hovering) of a control. The control must "catch" somehow the mouse move events. In your case just add a transparent layer below the ContentPresenter. Once hovering was detected the visible layers "catched" the mouse events.

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="hoverButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="hoverRect2" Fill="DarkGreen" Visibility="Hidden" Opacity="0.2" Width="{TemplateBinding Button.Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Button.Height}"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle x:Name="hoverRect" Fill="Black" Visibility="Hidden" Opacity="1" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Width}" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Height}" Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Margin}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Stretch}" ImageSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Source}"/>
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="hoverRect" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="hoverRect2" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: That's awesome - works like a charm. I tried a lot of different things, never thought that it would be that easy.